# Could not find/install babel plugin 'proposal-decorators' on CodeSandbox with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, babeljs, codesandbox

I'm trying to use Codesandbox in React project, but I'm stuck with error: Could not find/install babel plugin 'proposal-decorators': Cannot find plugin 'proposal-decorators' or 'babel-plugin-proposal-decorators'.
Error happens when I adding firebase utility in the project. On my local machine everythings fine.
Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-sun-r1bcqv

I tried to:

1. Install babel/plugin-proposal-decorators and add `"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "7.18.2"` in dependencies of package.json
2. Install babel and add `"babel": "6.23.0"` in dependencies of package.json
3. Create babel.confing.json file and add `{"plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators"]}` into that config

What cause the problem? Why there is babel/plugin-proposal-decorators if I didn't add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of importing SVG as a ReactComponent. It can't be done in sandboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I solved that problem by decreasing the version of

1. react-scripts to 2.0.3